# Sybase --Create Trigger giving syntax error for Referencing new as new old as old clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers, sap-ase

I am using Sybase ASE 15.0.3 and DBArtisan 8.5.3.

I am trying to create a trigger that puts data into audit tables when a table gets updated.

My code is something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER AUDIT_TRG ON TABLE A
FOR INSERT,UPDATE 
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
```

I  am getting a syntax error stating incorrect syntax near referencing. If I specify only old or new i get a different error as OLD or NEW is not valid identifier or something like that (I am unable to remember the exact error)

I even tried using :old and :new but they dont seem to be working.

Please let me know how can i access the old and new record values of the table being updated.

Comment: Maybe try reading the [documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands29.htm)? Sybase, like SQL Server, has `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables, rather than `old` and `new`.

Answer (score 0):

To use `new` and `old` you don't need to create a reference for `new as new` and `old as old`.

For example, you have to do it like this:

```
new.record_name
old.record_name
```

If you want to use some variable then you have to create a referencing like this:

```
referencing OLD as some_variable
```

And then you use this variable in the following way:

```
some_variable.record_name
```

Comment: Could you add a little more description about the explanation you provide?